# Print out a specific part of the output result in python

Tags: python, printing, subprocess

I have a function that does some thing and displays a line of output mixed between integer and strings.

However, I just want to print out the last part of the output which is the number 5 that comes after the dots:
The number 5 is the value of the OID and it could be 5( as On)
Or 6(as OFF).

[image]

Is there any way how can I specify that in print or if condition?

Here is the function:

```
import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.Popen(["powershell.exe",

              "snmpwalk -v1 -c public 192.168.178.213 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9986.3.22.1.6.1.1.15"],

              stdout=sys.stdout)
p.communicate()
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are trying to achieve and also the blue arrow does not seem to be pointing at the arrow 13. My *guess* is that you want to store the output of the subprocess (maybe with [subprocess.check_output](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) ) and then use regex to parse it

Comment: Yeah Lvaylo.. i want to store the output (only the number5) and use it someware agine.

Comment: Then read through the doc of the function I linked to. You will then be able to store the output. Separately read about how you use regexes in python (in particular re.search) to try to do the second part - extract only the number 5

Comment: import subprocess, sys

p = subprocess.check_output("snmpwalk -v1 -c public 192.168.178.213 .1.3.6.1.4.1.9986.3.22.1.6.1.1.13")
#X=print (int(p[60:70]))


if (int(p[60:70]))== 5 :
    print('HD')

else:
    print('SD').      ###### this gives me what i want.. only the number 5.